# prepare(for: sender:) not getting called during segue from button to tab bar controller (in Swift 4, Xcode 9)

Tags: swift, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller, prepared-statement, segue

I am writing an app with two tabs. In the first tab, the user selects some settings. Then they click on the second tab to randomly draw and display cards based on the settings in the first tab. At the bottom of the view in the second tab, there's a reshuffle button. I have the button segue'd to the (custom) UITabBarViewController with a overridden prepare(for: sender:) function directing it to return to the second tab immediately. After reading several questions on here which all the same thing, I'm certain I've done everything correctly, and according to all the answers, it *should* work.

However, it's only going to the first tab. I can click on the 2nd tab again, and it's reshuffling, and displaying a new set of cards properly, so there's no problem there. However, whenever the reshuffle button is clicked, prepare() is never called, hence why it goes to the first tab and not the 2nd. Why is prepare() not being called?

Here's what I have, storyboard and code:

[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtG3f.png)

```
class MainTabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

// var nextViewNumber = Int()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "reshuffleSegue") {
        if let tabVC = segue.destination as? UITabBarController {
            tabVC.selectedIndex = 2
        }
    }
}
}
```

Edited to add: if there's another method to get the intended effect, I'd be happy to use it instead.

Comment: I'm sure. The breakpoint was never reached.

Comment: first line of prepare()

Comment: Yes, I see what your mistake is. See my answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put your implementation of the `prepare(for:)` method in the wrong class. It goes in the source view controller, which is the Draw Cards view controller — not the tab bar view controller.

However, you should also note that you have a disastrous cycle of segues in your storyboard: you have a show segue from Draw Cards to Main Tab Bar, and a parent-child relationship from Main Tab Bar to Draw Cards. Your app is doomed. You should rethink your architecture entirely.

Comment: which class would that be? I just tried it in DrawCardsTabBarController, but that's not calling it either. And it seems UIButton doesn't have a prepare(for: source:) method.

Comment: I have no idea what class it would be. It's your storyboard. Look and see what class controls the reshuffle button.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. It was DrawCardsTabBarController, but then there was another problem. After a bit of finangling with the code, I got it working :)

Comment: Okay, but see my second paragraph. You should not be doing a show segue from a tab bar controller's child to the tab bar controller. You can end up with thousands of copies of the same view controller - not good.

Comment: what would be a smarter method? Sorry, I'm new at this.

Comment: Method to do _what_? I don't understand what you're trying to do. You are already _in_ the tab bar controller, so why would you want to _segue_ to it? The whole idea makes no sense.

Comment: If the goal is to change the selected index, then just tell the tab bar controller to change the selected index! It is `self.tabBarController`.

Comment: I'm trying to refresh the tab bar controller (which contains a table view) with a new list of drawn cards. So I need to trigger a refresh of the tab bar view or the table itself.